# Fragment and menu display

Tags: android

In my homepageactivity I have taken two fragments. one fragment is"Created by me" and another one is"Shared with me". I want to show different menus in both the fragment depending on the user's access type. I have created just one xml for both the fragments. what should i do to get different menus??

Comment: please show some code you wrote and explain what you tried so far.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21704700/different-menu-for-different-fragments?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

create menu files like **menu1.xml** , **menu2.xml**. and put the menu depends upon your Fragment.